# Drag and Drop Upload uses Dropzone.js in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, drag-and-drop, image-uploading, dropzone.js

An error occurred after "Adding Image" or "Drag and Drop" an image. Also, it's not uploaded into the destination folder.

[image: Error After Add a Image or Drag and Drop a Image]

Upload Error Code:

```
   <html> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"/> <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/> <style> /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui... */ html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;} html { background: #eee; padding: 10px } img { border: 0; } #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; } .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 } .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; } .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; } .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; } .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; } .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; } .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto } .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; } .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px } .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; } .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; cursor: default; } .sf-reset a img { border:none; } .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; } .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; } .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif } .sf-reset .exception_counter { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; float: left; display: block; } .sf-reset .exception_title { margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; display: block; } .sf-reset .exception_message { margin-left: 3em; display: block; } .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; } .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 16px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 16px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 16px; border-bottom-right-radius: 16px; border-bottom-left-radius: 16px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; word-wrap: break-word; } .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 16px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 16px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 16px; border-top-left-radius: 16px; border-top-right-radius: 16px; border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; } .sf-reset a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; } .sf-reset a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; } .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; } .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; } </style> </head> <body> <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset"> <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1> <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix"> 1/1 <abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError">FatalThrowableError</abbr> in ImageRepository.php line 18: Access to undeclared static property: App\Image::$rules </h2> <div class="block"> <ol class="traces list_exception"> <li> in ImageRepository.php line 18</li> <li>at <abbr title="App\Logic\Image\ImageRepository">ImageRepository</abbr>->upload(array('_token' => '0tyWiynSc7MLXoUKIdFsUGRlGEJONb4DmPuTxIBJ', 'file' => object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile">UploadedFile</abbr>))) in ImageController.php line 25</li> <li>at <abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\ImageController">ImageController</abbr>->postUpload()</li> <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(array(object(<abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\ImageController">ImageController</abbr>), 'postUpload'), array()) in Controller.php line 55</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Controller">Controller</abbr>->callAction('postUpload', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->dispatch(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), object(<abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\ImageController">ImageController</abbr>), 'postUpload') in Route.php line 189</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->runController() in Route.php line 144</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->run(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Router.php line 642</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 53</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings">SubstituteBindings</abbr>->handle(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 137</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 33</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken">VerifyCsrfToken</abbr>->handle(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 137</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 33</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession">ShareErrorsFromSession</abbr>->handle(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 137</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 33</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in StartSession.php line 64</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession">StartSession</abbr>->handle(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 137</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 33</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse</abbr>->handle(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 137</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 33</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies">EncryptCookies</abbr>->handle(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 137</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 33</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 104</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Router.php line 644</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->runRouteWithinStack(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Router.php line 618</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->dispatchToRoute(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Router.php line 596</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->dispatch(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Kernel.php line 268</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 53</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode">CheckForMaintenanceMode</abbr>->handle(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 137</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 33</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Pipeline.php line 104</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(object(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in Kernel.php line 150</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in Kernel.php line 117</li> <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->handle(object(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in index.php line 53</li> <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>require_once('G:\Laravel-Xampp7\htdocs\ecommerce\public\index.php') in server.php line 21</li> </ol> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your error says you are using rules undeclared static property of your model `App\Image`

if its static property you need to declare it in your model `App\Image` using

`public static $rules = ['image' => 'required'];`

Comment: Thanks, But same error after add the code into Image Model

Comment: keep and eye on your network tab of developer tools, it will log your post request and give html output which will tell you what error its facing.

Comment: Console give a error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

After click the console link Error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: My Route:

`Route::get('/', ['as' => 'upload', 'uses' => 'ImageController@getUpload']);
Route::post('upload', ['as' => 'upload-post', 'uses' =>'ImageController@postUpload']);
Route::post('upload/delete', ['as' => 'upload-remove', 'uses' =>'ImageController@deleteUpload']);`